# Sortable divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have page that has sorting for divs. Basically you can click button and it's sorts divs below. This works fine. Now I would like to extend it a bit but not sure how. What I would like it to do is, that when you press for example year sorting button once, its sorts DESC but when click again, then it sorts ASC.

So here is my current implementation:

```
function sorting(parent, childSelector, sortKey) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(sortKey, a).text();
        var vB = $(sortKey, b).text();
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

$('#sPrice').data("sortKey", "span.price");
$('#sStyle').data("sortKey", "span.style");
$('#sYear').data("sortKey", "span.year");

$(".sort").click(function() {
   sorting($('#sortThis'), '.sortable', $(this).data("sortKey"));
});
```

HTML & jQuery example is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPGrJB

So what I want that if user clicks for example Style once, it sorts DESC, if clicks again then sorts ASC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/477/

I used an attribute which stores the value whether the last sort is ascending or descending

JS:

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector, dir) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function (a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        if (dir == 'up') return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
        else return (vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA < vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
$('#sPrice').data("sortKey", "span.price");
$('#sStyle').data("sortKey", "span.style");
$('#sYear').data("sortKey", "span.year");

$('.show').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.extra_content').toggleClass('hidden');
});
/* sort on button click */
$("button.btnSort").click(function () {
    var asc = $(this).attr('asc') == 'up' ? 'down' : 'up';
    $(this).attr('asc', asc);
    sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", $(this).data("sortKey"), asc);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sortThis">
    <div id="1">Price:<span class="price">20</span>  <span class="style">blue</span>  <span class="year">2014</span>  <span class="show">Show</span>
        <div class="extra_content hidden">Loremipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">Price:<span class="price">23</span>  <span class="style">red</span>  <span class="year">2009</span>  <span class="show">Show</span>
        <div class="extra_content hidden">Loremipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div id="3">Price:<span class="price">10</span>  <span class="style">red</span>  <span class="year">1999</span>  <span class="show">Show</span>
        <div class="extra_content hidden">Loremipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div id="4">Price:<span class="price">29</span>  <span class="style">green</span>  <span class="year">2012</span>  <span class="show">Show</span>
        <div class="extra_content hidden">Loremipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div id="5">Price:<span class="price">35</span>  <span class="style">blue</span>  <span class="year">2011</span>  <span class="show">Show</span>
        <div class="extra_content hidden">Loremipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button asc='down' id="sPrice" class="btnSort">Sort By Price</button>
<br />
<button asc='down' id="sYear" class="btnSort">Sort By Year</button>
<br />
<button asc='down' id="sStyle" data-sortKey="span.style" class="btnSort">Sort By Style</button>
<br />
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course so simple. For some reason I was trying to solver this much harder way. Thanks!